# How to save quotes in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo, quotes

Whenever I add a single quote (') or a double quote (") in my PHP formfield, it will be saved in my MySQL DB as `&#34;` / `&#39;`. How can save the 'real' "quotes" in my DB?

I tried to prevent this by making a secure Mysql connection thru PDO, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

So here's the important part of my code:

```
    $insert_hello = filter_var($_POST['hello'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $dbh->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO testtable (data) VALUES (:hello)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':hello', $insert_hello, PDO::PARAM_STR);      
    $stmt->execute();
```

**Some background information:**

The server runs on PHP v5.2.12-0.

The DBStorage engine is InnoDB and has its client-, connection-, results- and system charset are set to utf8.

The DB field has its collation set to utf8_unicode_ci.

Magic quotes are disabled thru .htaccess.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Jroen

Comment: It appears to me that you are doing the conversion with filter_var.  Why are you filtering if you want to store the raw string?

Comment: Hey! I suppose you are right Le Dorfier. The filter_var is unnecessary and is indeed the one that turns the quotes into hex codes. When taking this out, will this make my script vulnerable to injections?

Comment: le dorfier is right, I never used PDO, but looks like the SQL escaping should be done by `$stmt->bindParam(...)`, so there is no need to `filter_var()`... Just try to change that first line to `$inset_hello = $_POST['hello'];` and see what happens while posting some text containing single quotes..

Comment: @Jroen, <quote>"When taking this out, will this make my script vulnerable to injections?"</quote>, no, since PDO should sanitize data for you. If it doesn't, then change DBAL :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just to formalize the correct answer:

The problem is caused by `filter_var()` that converts some characters into HTML entities. There is no need to manually sanitize the data since PDO does that for you.

You can just write something like this, that should work just fine:

```
$dbh->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO testtable (data) VALUES (:hello)");
$stmt->bindParam(':hello', $_POST['hello'], PDO::PARAM_STR);      
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to leave this as is and html decode on reading.

Comment: Sorry Francis, no can do. I don't want to leave it like this, because i'll be using the data from these fields in my CRM database. (which does not decode)

Comment: no, definitely this is *not* the best idea. Just a very ugly workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function `$decoded_insert_hello = html_entity_decode($insert_hello, ENT_QUOTES)` to do this.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: According to this guy (see: http://bit.ly/iFr2uz) there should be no need to do the decoding. 

He sais: "_The beauty (and power) of using parameterized queries is that the underlying driver takes care of quoting and escaping for you (while also helping to protect against SQL injection), the underlying driver will appropriately quote and escape the parameter value so that the correct data is inserted (i.e. Brian’s data)._

Comment: these are two completely different things. your database just stores text strings, it doesn't know where the strings come from or transform them in any way. it simply stores them as you provide, only escaping any special characters that could confuse the database or expose you to injection attacks. you are passing in an html encoded string and you essentially want to transform it into a plain ascii string, the database won't do this for you: it would be like passing in a string in french and asking your database to translate it to english before storing - you have to do that yourself first.

Comment: (cont) once you pass the string to you database engine it will escape any characters that have any significance in sql, but it doesn't know anything about the html format or what characters have significance in html. (hope i am making myself clear, the explanation was a bit long winded).

Answer (score 0):

This is how my data as API response looks like, which I want to store in the MYSQL database. It contains Quotes, HTML Code , etc.

Example:-

```
{

rewardName: "Cabela's eGiftCard $25.00",

shortDescription: '<p>adidas gift cards can be redeemed in over 150 adidas Sport Performance, adidas Originals, or adidas Outlet stores in the US, as well as online at&nbsp;<a href="http://adidas.com/">adidas.com</a>.</p>

terms: '<p>adidas Gift Cards may be redeemed for merchandise on&nbsp;<a href="http://adidas.com/">adidas.com</a>&nbsp;and in adidas Sport Performance, adidas Originals, and adidas Outlet stores in the United States.'

}
```

SOLUTION

```
CREATE TABLE `brand` (
`reward_name` varchar(2048),
`short_description` varchar(2048),
`terms` varchar(2048),  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

While inserting , In followed **JSON.stringify()**

```
    let brandDetails= {
    rewardName: JSON.stringify(obj.rewardName),  
    shortDescription: JSON.stringify(obj.shortDescription),
    term: JSON.stringify(obj.term),
     }
```

Above  is the JSON object and below is the SQL Query that insert data into MySQL.

```
let query = `INSERT INTO brand (reward_name, short_description, terms) 
VALUES (${brandDetails.rewardName}, 
(${brandDetails.shortDescription}, ${brandDetails.terms})`;
```

Its worked....

[image]

If nothing works try this :

```
var res = str.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
var res = res.replace(/"/g, "\\\"");
```

It adds the \ escape character to all occurrences of ' and "

Not sure if its the correct/professional way to fix the issue

I'm guessing it will work but in actual content, every single and double quotes will be replaced with \ character